# !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 2585116)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase and I'm trying send some data to my database using the send message method below. When I call it I'm getting

> !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size =
>   2585116).

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String message = typeMessage.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
        String current_user_ref = "messages/" + mCurrentUserId + "/" +mChatUser;
        String chat_user_ref = "messages/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserId;

        DatabaseReference user_message_push = mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).push();
        String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

        Map messageMap = new HashMap();
        messageMap.put("message",message);
        messageMap.put("seen",false);
        messageMap.put("type","text");
        messageMap.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

        Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
        messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref + "/"  + push_id, messageMap);
        messageMap.put(chat_user_ref + "/" + push_id,messageMap);

        mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError !=null){
                    Log.d("CHAT App",databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the error part of my logcat.

```
12-27 12:43:05.667 16615-16615/com.myApp.myApp E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2585116)
12-27 12:43:05.672 16615-16615/com.myApp.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2585116 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
12-27 12:43:05.755 1653-1715/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'cff7e18 com.myApp.myApp/com.myApp.myApp.BottomNav (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error? Please use the [edit] link to add the information directly into the question.

Comment: @CindyMeister That's all I'm getting from the logcat when I call the method.